# Sort records in a list by their key

Tags: python

I am trying to sort records within a list using their 'key' (which is their name).
The records are formatted:

> CHARLES 2 4 DALLAS TX
>
> RICK   6 9 AUSTIN TX
>
> BOB    9 0 KELLER TX

How can I sort these records within the last by their first name only? My code so far is:

```
list_of_records = []
for line in my_file:
   list_of_records.append(line)
```

The file I am reading from contains only 3 records but they will always be unsorted by name and I can not manually sort the text file.

Comment: what have you code so far?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html

Comment: So if there are two records with the same name, they must remain in the same order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `key` argument to Python's [builtin `sorted` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

Assuming your records are tuples:

```
records = [ 
  ("CHARLES", 2, 4, "DALLAS TX"),
  ("RICK", 6, 9, "AUSTIN TX"),
  ("BOB", 9, 0, "KELLER TX")
] 

sorted(records, key=lambda rec: rec[0])

# Produces:                                                                                                                                    
[('BOB', 9, 0, 'KELLER TX'),
 ('CHARLES', 2, 4, 'DALLAS TX'),
 ('RICK', 6, 9, 'AUSTIN TX')]
```

My recommendation would be to use [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to create a record class, and convert any text to the correct types (e.g. integers) as early as possible.  (The sample code below omits conversion to integers for simplicity.)

If you records are strings, you can call `line.split(" ")` on each element to produce lists.

```
my_file = [ 
    "CHARLES 2 4 DALLAS TX", 
    "RICK 6 9 AUSTIN TX", 
    "BOB 9 0 KELLER TX", 
] 

Record = collections.namedtuple("Record", "name, i, j, city, state") 
records = [Record(*line.split(" ")) for line in my_file] 

sorted(records, key=lambda rec: rec.name)                                                                                                                                  
# Result: 
# [Record(name='BOB', i='9', j='0', city='KELLER', state='TX'),
#  Record(name='CHARLES', i='2', j='4', city='DALLAS', state='TX'),
#  Record(name='RICK', i='6', j='9', city='AUSTIN', state='TX')]
```